# Flock for delete entry in text no work me

Tags: php, function

I create one function for delete entry in little file in txt format , the problem it´s when i go delete entry show me this message :

**Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in**

**The Script Function :**

```
<?php
function delete_entry($name_file_db,$id_entry)
{
$fil_del=file("".$name_file_db."");
$fd=fopen("".$name_file_db."","w");

if (flock($fd,LOCK_EX)) 
{
ftruncate($fd,0); 
fputs($fd,"".$fil_del[0]."");
for($de=1;$de<sizeof($fil_del);$de++)
{   
if($de=="".$id_entry."")
{
fputs($fd,"");  
}
else
{
fputs($fd,"".$fil_del[$de].""); 
}   
}
fflush($fd); 
flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fd);
}
else
{
if($db_activate_msg_bugs=="si")
{
print "Busy File";
}
}

}
?>
```

I don´t know why no works , i try differents combinations but continue fail

Thank´s Regards

Comment: Please try to format your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fd=fopen("".$name_file_db."","w")` probably didn't open a file. [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns `false` if it fails:

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

---

BTW `ftruncate()` is needless, `fopen()` in mode `w` implicitly truncates the file. This does also break your code. The blocked process is truncating your file! Consider using a dedicated lock file or open the file nondeconstructive (e.g. mode `c`).